# Where is the code behind file in JSP?

Tags: jsp

I am very new to JSP. I need to find in which file the redirecting code is? I am typing URL in browser like this

```
/home/userpage.htm?method=veiwuser    --> Its opening viewuser.jsp

/home/userpage.htm?method=deleteuser  -->Its opening deleteuser.jsp page
```

How can I find the code behind this magic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Globally search for 'userpage.htm' in your project and find the

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/**/userpage.htm" ...
```

which contains the code for the userpage.htm

Answer (score 0):

Check whether this application uses an MVC framework like Spring MVC or Struts. This type of thing is typically handled by the Controller servlet.

However, the behavior you describe could also be done by a javascript redirect call from the htm page, or a custom servlet.

Comment: Yes there is /WebContent/WEB-INF/spring folder